# Alias a module defined in the same file in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've got a module like that:

```
module Foo.Bar (
  Bar,
  not
) where
data Bar = Some Int | Other Int
not (Some x) = ...
not (Other x) = Foo.Bar.not $ Some x
```

As you see, I have to write `Foo.Bar.not` because `not` is defined in `Prelude`.

Is there a way to alias `Foo.Bar` to e.g. `B` so that I can write `not (Other x) = B.not $ Some x` in the very file where `not` is defined?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. But note that you can circumvent the name clash by using  `import Prelude hiding (not)`. — On another note, it seems a pretty bad idea to call this function `not`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this isn't possible using anything compliant with the Haskell specification and working in GHC.

Anyway, there are ways a similar result can be achieved:

- As @leftaroundabout [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608734/alias-a-module-defined-in-the-same-file-in-haskell/35612830#comment58901882_35608734), `import Prelude hiding (not)` will help.
- @PyRulez' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35612830/2757025) suggests creating a module called `B` and exporting that module within `Foo.Bar`
- @Zeta's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35610076/2757025) suggests aliasing `Foo.Bar.not` to `notBar`

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be technically possible, if a bit painful, in GHC. For example, I would expect things to work if you produced the following two files (following the [documentation on mutual recursion](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html#mutual-recursion)):

```
-- Foo/Bar.hs-boot
module Foo.Bar where
import Prelude(Either)
not :: Either a a -> a

-- Foo/Bar.hs
module Foo.Bar where
import Prelude (Either(..))
import {-# SOURCE #-} Foo.Bar as B
not (Left x) = x
not (Right x) = B.not (Left x)
```

However, when I try this, I get a complaint that `B.not` is not in scope. I suspect this is a bug in GHC, and have filed a ticket [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11637) to see if the devs agree.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to alias `Foo.Bar` to e.g. `B` [...]?

While I'm not sure whether there is a way to alias a module in itself, you could easily alias `not`:

```
module Foo.Bar (
   Bar,
   Foo.Bar.not
 ) where

data Bar = Some Int | Other Int

notBar, not :: Bar -> Bool
notBar (Some  x) = ...
notBar (Other x) = notBar (Some x)

-- Use 'notBar' in this module, but export only 'not'.    
not = notBar
```

Given that `notBar` and `B.not` differ only a single character in length, I think this is more or less a valid solution. Furthermore, it doesn't depend on any compiler quirks.

Alternatively, hide the bindings that use the same name from `Prelude`:

```
module Foo.Bar (
   Bar,
   not
 ) where

import Prelude hiding (not)    

data Bar = Some Int | Other Int

not :: Bar -> Bool
not (Some  x) = ...
not (Other x) = notBar (Some x)
```

Comment: Well, if you're going to change the question, a simple `NoImplicitPrelude` (or `import Prelude ()` or `import Prelude hiding (not)`) seems like it fixes things without spurious names or redefinition gymnastics.

Comment: @DanielWagner: Sure, but the question seems a bit like an XY problem. My answer originally contained `import Prelude hiding (...)`, but that was more or less already covered by yours, so I removed it before posting.

Comment: Your solution to an XY problem is to post an answer covering Z...?

Comment: @DanielWagner *nomen omen*

Comment: Anyway it should be noted that `not = notBar` without a type signature may trigger the monomorphism restriction (depending on the ghc version etc) and thus be more monomorphic than it needs to be.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Eh, `not` has a type signature (although it's slightly hidden). Also, I think I might be missing something on your "nomen omen" remark.

Comment: Oh, didn't see that. Anyway I was just jokingly pointing out that Daniel Wagner said you were trying to cover the Z in an XY problem when your nickname is Zeta so... [nomen omen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_determinism)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
module Foo.Bar (
  Bar,
  B.not
) where

import qualified Foo.Bar as B (not)

data Bar = Some Int | Other Int
not (Some x) = undefined
not (Other x) = B.not $ Some x
```

be warned though, that if you are using GHC, you will probably need to do some extra work: https://wiki.haskell.org/Mutually_recursive_modules#GHC

Comment: If you still have to use `Foo.Bar.not` instead of `B.not`, what's the point of going to all the extra trouble of making this a recursive module import? And if you say you can use `B.not`, please test this. I did, and it's not so easy as you might think.

Comment: @DanielWagner Whoops, sorry, that's a typo.

Comment: @DanielWagner My compiler doesn't implement Mutually recursive modules (at least not very well).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a GHC compatible answer, although its a bit of a clutch:

```
-- B.hs
module B (
  Bar,
  B.not
) where
data Bar = Some Int | Other Int
not (Some x) = undefined
not (Other x) = B.not $ Some x
-- Foo.Bar.hs
module Foo.Bar (module Foo.Bar) where
import B as Foo.Bar
```

When `Foo.Bar` is imported, `Bar`, `not`, `Foo.Bar.Bar` and `Foo.Bar.not` are provided (the first two are suppresed if `Foo.Bar` is imported qualified.)